# Do these verbenas need deadheading?

Tags: flowers

I bought these verbenas thinking they don't need deadheading but there is something wrong with them and I don't understand if they need to be cleaned from the dead flowers or if there is something else they are suffering from. They are watered every day and get full sun
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verbenas do need deadheading really, particularly the annual kinds such as yours - they look a lot tidier if they are deadheaded, removing the long stems with the spent flowers on the end, and this will encourage the plant to produce more flowers. Info here https://www.thespruce.com/verbena-care-1315718. If they aren't blooming very well after deadheading, or still look a bit tatty, clip them back by up to a third to encourage new growth.